# Why does mpi4Py Scatter need to be done on Satellite Nodes with no data to scatter?

Tags: python, mpi4py

I'm new to `mpi4py`, but am trying to gain familiarity with it in order to soon parallelize some computational physics code. I have the following short script in order to test it.

```py
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

N = 8

if rank == 0: # main node
    P = np.empty(shape = (N, 3, 2))
    for n in range(0, size):
        P[n, :, :] = n
    
    coreP = np.empty(shape = (N//size, 3, 2), dtype = 'double')
    comm.Scatter(P, coreP)
    
    comm.barrier()
    print("core {0}/{1}, coreP:\n {2}\n".format(rank, size, coreP))

if rank != 0: # satellite node
    P = None
    coreP = np.empty(shape = (N//size, 3, 2), dtype = 'double')
    comm.Scatter(P, coreP) # what does this line do?
    
    comm.barrier()
    print("core {0}/{1}, coreP:\n {2}\n".format(rank, size, coreP))
```

From which I get the expected result:

```
core 6/8, coreP:
 [[[6. 6.]
  [6. 6.]
  [6. 6.]]]

core 5/8, coreP:
 [[[5. 5.]
  [5. 5.]
  [5. 5.]]]

...

core 3/8, coreP:
 [[[3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]
  [3. 3.]]]
```

Or some variation with the cores reordered. My question is, what is the point of the `comm.Scatter()` command within the satellite node routine? What is it sending, and why does my script output all `0`s if it is missing? Why don't I need a `root = 0` parameter?

I apologize if these are basic questions, and appreciate any clarification in advance. Thank you.